# Java - How to use PrintStream/OutputStream to print to the Command Line

Tags: java, outputstream, printstream

I know we can use PrintStream to print lines to a given file:

```
    PrintStream output;
    output = new PrintStream("./temp.txt");
    output .println("some output text");
```

However, can we use PrintStream to print lines to the **command line**?

I've looked through the Java docs and it seems PrintStream constructor can take a file path or an OutputStream (is there a OutputStream subclass that would print to command line?)

Comment: Sidenote: By definition `System.out` (stdout / Standard Outputstream) already is a `PrintStream`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
output = new PrintStream(System.out);
```

or actually,

```
output = System.out;
```

Similarly, you can do the same with `System.err`
... So why don't we just simply use System.out and System.err directly? *sout + tab* is quite fast to type in IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` or `System.error` are already `PrintStream` and we can use them to print the output to command line without creating a new `PrintStream` object that you are doing.

Advantage of using this printStream is that you can use `System.setOut()` or `System.setErr()` to set the printSteam of your choice

```
PrintStream output = new PrintStream("./temp.txt");
System.setOut(output);
```

Above will override the default Printstream of printing to command line and now calling `System.out.println()` will print everything in given file(temp.txt)

Comment: Note that using `System.setOut()` and `System.setErr()` replaces the standard output or standard error stream for the whole process. For a small, minimal console application this might be fine. For larger systems, complex unit/integration tests, etc., this can have severe consequences (if e.g. different parts of the system modifies these streams from multiple threads simultaneously).

Answer (score 0):

The PrintStream class provides methods to write data to another stream. To print to command line you can use `System.out` as out is an object of `PrintStream` class.

```
import java.io.*;  
class PrintStreamTest{  
  public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
    PrintStream pout=new PrintStream(System.out);  
    pout.println(1900);  
    pout.println("Hello Java");  
    pout.println("Welcome to Java");  
    pout.close();  
  }  
}
```

This will give output on command line as:

1900

Hello Java

Welcome to Java